# I'm trying to define a new customer address attribute that will be available in all the customer address forms (backend, frontend, checkout)

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-address, customer-address-attribute

So far I have managed to save the value in quote_address and `sales_order_address` when placing the order how can I save the value in the `customer_address_entity_varchar` table. when customer address saves in the address book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a customer address attribute

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer_address','attribute_name',array(
    'type'               => 'varchar',
    'label'              => 'Attribute Name,
    'input'              => 'text',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
));
```

Then save your value in this attribute